# Skin theme designer issue (vb.net express 2015)

Tags: vb.net, themes, designer, skin

I'm using custom theme (Net seal by Aeon Hack).

I opened a form, dragged NStheme from toolbar to the form. Project builds successfully.
But when I simply close form and then try to open it in designer mode, I get error:

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:
>
> The designer cannot process the code at line XX, please see the Task
>   List for details. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is
>   generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please
>   remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working on Visual Studio 2012